# openJSCAD include files

Tags: javascript, openjscad

I would like to load multiple files with `OpenJSCAD`.
I tried [1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenJSCAD_User_Guide#Maintaining_Larger_Projects) without any success.

I'm using `OpenJSCAD` with Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried both the offline and online versions.

Comment: You should explain your issue more in detail. Explain what you have tried, what you have done.

Comment: I am working on an answer see https://openjscad.nodebb.com/topic/6/dockerized-openjscad

Comment: see also https://github.com/jscad/OpenJSCAD.org/issues/245

Answer (score 2):

I have improved the [section on include of the Userguide](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=OpenJSCAD_User_Guide&stable=0#Including_Files)

You should be able to try it out with any of the three examples mentioned by putting the files of the examples in a folder and then drag and drop to OpenJSCAD

[image: ScreenShot of drag&drop result]

The result should be as in https://openjscad.org/#examples/platonics

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in a world where complicated things are easy and easy things are complicated!

The include command of OpenJSCAD will search for include file relatively to the URL of the including file and there are limits to this when you try to drag&drop files via the browser and the behavior seems to be much browser dependent.

So it would be easier if your "workspace" with the file you'd like to use would reside within the webservice that the OpenJSCAD solution offers.

In the examples section of OpenJSCAD there seems to be one use of the "include" statement at this time see:

https://www.openjscad.org/examples/globe.jscad

You can try it out via
https://www.openjscad.org/index.html#examples/globe.jscad

Please note that how on refresh you get an error message:

```
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /openjscad.jscadplatonics/maths_geodesic.jscad was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.openjscad.org Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

To get the same effect locally you'd have to create a sister directory of "examples" in your local installation. This will not work if you call "index.html" with a file url

file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/@jscad/openjscad/index.html#examples/globe.jscad

To show the principle of a "workspace" directory i have created a dockerized OpenJSCAD version which is available at:

It's also available via Docker Hub so you can simply try it out by running the command:

```
docker run --publish=8080:8080 --name openjscad  bitplan/openjscad:latest
```

You should now have an OpenJSCAD running in a docker container on your computer which you can try out with e.g.

http://localhost:8080/

and specifically

- http://localhost:8080/index.html#examples/globe.jscad
- http://localhost:8080/index.html#examples/platonics

to see the include usage.

Now we need to apply this principle to the workspace directory which is prepared in the docker container and ready to be mounted locally.

To get this working some rules need to be followed which are currently discussed at:
https://openjscad.nodebb.com/topic/6/dockerized-openjscad

Mount your workspace directory

```
docker run \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --name openjscad \
  --volume $HOME/openjscad/workspace:/openjscad/packages/web/examples/workspace \
  bitplan/openjscad:latest
```

now the file from your workspace should be available via the corresponding url.
To try things out you might want to copy the platonics folder from

https://github.com/jscad/OpenJSCAD.org/tree/master/packages/examples/platonics

to your workspace folder and try the access with:

http://localhost:8080/index.html#examples/workspace/platonics

now you should be all set to use

```
include()
```

as requested